# SQL Server Database Size Increasing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, signalr, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I am developing a ASP.NET Web Application with real time functionality by using ASP.NET SignalR.

The problem which I'm facing is the `SqlNotificationType`.

If I use `SqlNotificationType.Change`, I can't get the change notification from my database. The SQL 'ServiceBroker' is enabled for my database.

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        NotificationHub nHub = new NotificationHub();
        nHub.SendNotifications();
    }
}
```

But if I use `SqlNotificationType.Subscribe`, It just start notifying me the database changes but the database size starts growing with the every change made in the database.

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Subscribe)
    {
        NotificationHub nHub = new NotificationHub();
        nHub.SendNotifications();
    }
}
```

Whenever a change is made in the database table, a new subscription must be created by re-executing the query after each notification is processed.

**It increases the Database Size**

**Given below is the function to sendNotifications to all the connected clients.**

```
public string SendNotifications()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MCNServerconnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            const string query = "Select ID, AgentID, DiallerID, Call_Direction, Extension, Call_ID  from [MCNServer].[dbo].[CallsDataRecords] where ID = 915";
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
                }
            }
        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(json).ToString();
    }
```

The solution I found is to decrease the database QueryNotificationTimeOut to expire the notifications.

How to Invalidate Cache Entry inorder to eliminate querynotifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching and debugging my code, I figured out the problem and resolve it.

The `SqlNotificationType.Change` wasn't working for me and when I used `SqlNotificationType.Subscribe` it works for me but it increases by database size by subscribing **Query Notifications** and they are not getting expired due to unauthorized access of database.

So the problem due to database size was increasing while I was using Sql Dependency and enabled Service Broker for my database is **unauthorized access to database with sa user.**

Due to this problem, queries notifications are not getting expired and they are adding in to the database whenever a change it made in the database. That's why the database size was growing.

So to solve this problem I alter my database and set authorization to sa user and its working fine for me.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[MCNServer] TO [sa];
```

Now no query notification is pending in the database as `sa` user is now authorized to access this database and I'm using `SqlNotificationType.Change` and it is working now.